# Keycloak OTP based Login

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to enable login in my application using following call flow:

Step 1: User visits the Application website and enters the Mobile Number or Username.

Step 2: Application requests Keycloak to generate the OTP for the user associated with the username. The OTP returned by Keycloak is sent to User via Email or SMS.

Step 3: User enters the OTP and the application sends the OTP to Keycloak to validate against that user.

Step 4: Keycloak validates the OTP and responds back with Access Token.

In the above call flow, I need 2 APIs from Keycloak.

1. API to generate the OTP for given username
2. API to validate the OTP provided by the User and respond back with Access Token

Please let me know if this login call flow is possible or not using the latest Keycloak version.

Comment: Did you already have a look at the documentation and authentication spi?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929788/keycloak-otp-for-read-only-federated-users/72485866#72485866

Comment: @Safvan Thanks in advance. Did you solve it ? I need to implement the same logic

Comment: Take a look at keycloak two factor email authenticator provider https://github.com/mesutpiskin/keycloak-2fa-email-authenticator

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution for an [SMS authenticator](https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator) (See the videos).

Then, duplicate browser flow and edit it. Remove "user password form" step and place "username form" instead of that. Place SMS authentication instead of OTP step. Bind the new flow as your default browser flow.
In this scenario users must enter their username/email/phone and in the next step, they must enter code which has sent as SMS to their phones.